# Talend parse date: unable to parse

Tags: date, talend

I'm trying to `insert data` in my Database, my input is a string, representing a date in this format: `yyyyMMdd ("20140525")`

I try this in talend :

`TalendDate.parseDate("yyyyMMdd",row1.date_pre_contrat)`

but at runtime it does not work...

I've also tried

`TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row1.date_pre_contrat)`

but the result is the same.

Does someone have a any clue on what the problem is?

Comment: the parse String is correct, so further details re needed...what do you mean whith "it does not work"?

Comment: in what variable/schema column are you storing the return results of this TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row1.date_pre_contrat). as it returns date datatype..

Comment: The error I obtain is 

Exception in component tXMLMap_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "DAT_PRE_CTR         "
 at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:744)
 at decisionnel.insert_0_1.insert.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(insert.java:1648)
 at decisionnel.insert_0_1.insert.runJobInTOS(insert.java:2214)
 at decisionnel.insert_0_1.insert.main(insert.java:2082)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "DAT_PRE_CTR         "
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:742)
 ... 3 more

Comment: And I try to store it in a date field (dd-MM-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

it was because i didn't tell Talend not to analyse the first line which contains the title.

Sorry for this